# How do I add a fixed value to get_post_meta();?

Tags: post-meta

I'm using the following to display a custom field value in my posts:

`<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wikipedia', true); ?>`

How do I add this value to the output, where '$tag' takes the tag of the post:

`- <a href="wikipedia.org/wiki/**$tag**">Wikipedia</a>`

What I've tried, unsuccessfully:

`<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wikipedia', true . '- <a href="wikipedia.org/wiki/$tag">Wikipedia</a>'); ?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php $tag = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wikipedia', true); ?>

<?php if (isset($tag) && $tag != '') : ?>
    <a href="wikipedia.org/wiki/<?php echo $tag; ?>" title="Wiki this!">Wikipedia</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

To explain it a bit: First you put the data in a variable, then if the variable has some data, it will show the link and echo the data after /wiki/. You can use the variable also on other places like so:  `<a href="wikipedia.org/wiki/<?php echo $tag; ?>">Wikipedia (<?php echo $tag; ?>)</a>`

Comment: thanks but the problem with that is that the link will appear even when I don't add content to the custom field.

Comment: You don't need the isset check, it'll come back as an empty value if it's not set or if it's empty, so it's better to use `if( !empty( $whatever ) )` for the conditional block.